# Postgresql how to change row to column

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

lets say i have a table like this:

```
type       success    failed
type 1     10         1
type 2     4          0
type 3     5          3
```

and i want to create a table like this with query

```
type     state      count
type 1   success    10
type 1   failed     1
type 2   success    4
type 2   failed     0
type 3   success    5
type 3   failed     3
```

what query should i type to show a table like above?

using colpivot or crosstab?

Comment: Question stilla says "I want to crete a table" you might want to edit that

Comment: What have you tried ? is your current query showing you any errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `UNION ALL`

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT type,'success' state,success count  FROM T
  UNION ALL
  SELECT type,'failed' ,failed  FROM T
) t
ORDER BY type,state desc
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3f720a/3/0)**:

```
|   type |   state | count |
|--------|---------|-------|
| type 1 | success |    10 |
| type 1 |  failed |     1 |
| type 2 | success |     4 |
| type 2 |  failed |     0 |
| type 3 | success |     5 |
| type 3 |  failed |     3 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a VALUES clause:

```
select t.type, u.*
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (  
    values ('success', t.success), ('failed', t.failed)
  ) as u(state,count)
order by t.type, u.state;
```

[Online Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=66dd4896fab96d0e6c20136499ba5698)